# Storing image in xml file for iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I working on iPad application in which i am rendering the data from the xml file. In application i have to display image related to the object. I have two ways to do it
first is add the image in my project folder and add the name of image in xml file

```
<image>image1.png<image>
```

and after that:

```
image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:food.image];
```

And another way is to store image into the xml.

which is the best way? If i store the whole image into xml then do i need to add the image in my application folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefer you to store image path in xml like http://car.amarhost.net/blogo/00001.png. So that you don't have to store image in local storage and if you have a large number of image, you can download them asynchronously like [lazy loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an XML Parser to read the other data for your app, then you should simply parse the image tag, too, but I think having it in the bundle is better than reading it from XML, if that's a static image and won't change, and would be more efficient.